# What is the right order of Spring profiles?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

Tell me how to properly configure the order of Spring profiles?

I have lib library with *application-lib.yml* file

```
lib:
   test:
     name: Lib
```

And the application itself with two configuration files
*application.yml*

```
server:
   port: 8080
lib:
   test:
     name: App
```

and *application-local.yml*

```
server:
   port: 4444
```

I launch the application in the following order of profiles - *lib,{ other profiles },default,local*

But for some reason the property does not change for me

**lib.test.name** - it remains the old value **Lib**

I found [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), but didn't quite figure out how to set up the order I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation you referred to:

> Config data files are considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Application properties packaged inside your jar
>    (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 2. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar
>    (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 3. Application properties outside of your packaged jar
>    (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 4. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar
>    (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).

`application.properties` or, in your case, `application.yml` are always considered first. Therefore placing the `default` profile on the list of active profiles does not affect the order of considering `application.yml` and the value `lib.test.name` is overridden by profile-specific properties.

Consider introducing a new profile, such as `application-app.yml`:

```yaml
lib:
   test:
     name: App
```

Finally, replace the `default` profile with the `app` profile: `lib, { other profiles }, app, local`.